# Qt.Key_Space does not trigger

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

When trying to create a timer, I want to to use `Space` to activate the timer function I have created:

```py
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, e):
        # if e.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
        if (e.key() == Qt.Key_T):
            self.isCounting = not self.isCounting
            if self.isCounting == True:
                self.timerStart = time.time()
            else:
                #return elapsed time
                print(time.time() - self.timerStart)
```

However, this does not work. Any other buttons I use, I.E. "t", "0" etc... do work. Is something else using `Space` by default, or what could be causing this problem?

MRE:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import time
import sys

class Listener(QObject):
    def __init__(self, button):
        super().__init__(button)
        self._button = button
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def button(self):
        return self._button

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.button and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920
        self.SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080
        self.WIN_HEIGHT = self.SCREEN_HEIGHT*.8
        self.WIN_WIDTH = self.SCREEN_WIDTH/2
        self.isCounting = False
        self.timerStart = time.time()
        self.setGeometry(self.SCREEN_WIDTH/2-self.WIN_WIDTH/2,self.SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-self.WIN_HEIGHT/2, self.WIN_WIDTH, self.WIN_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle('Timer')

        scrambleButton = QPushButton(self)
        scrambleButton.setText('New Scramble')
        scrambleButtonGeometry = QRect(self.WIN_WIDTH/2-65, 80, 130,35)
        scrambleButton.setGeometry(scrambleButtonGeometry)
        scrambleButton.clicked.connect(lambda: print('hey'))
        listener = Listener(scrambleButton)

        self.show()

        
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, e):
    #   if e.key() == Qt.Key_Space: 
      if (e.key() == Qt.Key_T):
          self.isCounting = not self.isCounting
          if self.isCounting == True:
              self.timerStart = time.time()
          else:
              #return elapsed time
              print(time.time() - self.timerStart)
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that although the KeyPress event is not sent to the QPushButton, it is not ignored, so the window is not notified. The solution is to ignore the keyPress and keyRelease in the eventFilter:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.button and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        event.ignore()
        return True
    if obj is self.button and event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease:
        event.ignore()
    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

An easier solution is to use QShortcut:

```
    # ...
    self.show()

    shorcut = QShortcut(Qt.Key_Space, self, autoRepeat=False)
    shorcut.activated.connect(self.process_time)

def process_time(self):
    self.isCounting = not self.isCounting
    if self.isCounting == True:
        self.timerStart = time.time()
    else:
        print(time.time() - self.timerStart)
```

Comment: The second part works well, thank you. I also have a problem with key repeats after a certain delay that act like it's pressing and releasing constantly, activating the shortcut in the process. Should I ask another question about that, or is it related to the QShortcut?

Comment: @CarlosMedina Try my update, what happens is that as long as you press the button the events are still sent every T seconds, this behavior is disabled by setting the autoRepeat property of the QShortcut to False.